# php Laravel 9 Undefined variable $questions

Tags: php, laravel, variables, undefined

I have two tables: Users and Question and I have a form to create questions and an index.blade.php view to show all the questions created. But I have this error, when I want to show the index view with all the questions created:

> Undefined variable $questions

This is my UserModel:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
];


protected $hidden = [
    'password',
    'remember_token',
    'two_factor_recovery_codes',
    'two_factor_secret',
];


protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];


protected $appends = [
    'profile_photo_url',
];

//Relationship onetomany with Questions table
public function questions(){
    return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
}
```

This is my Question Model:

```
use HasFactory;

protected $fillable = ['question', 'answer', 'user_id'];

//Relationship with User table
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

This is my Controller to send the index view which is in a folder called admin, the collection of created questions

```
public function index()
{

    $questions = Question::all();

    return view('admin.index', compact('questions'));
}
```

And this is the foreach in the index to show the questions created, the foreach is inside of a table:

```php
@foreach($questions as $question)
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>{{$question->question}}</td>
        <td>{{$question->answer}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

And this is the route in web.php

```php
Route::resource('admin/question', QuestionController::class)->middleware('auth')->names('admin.question');
```

Comment: Please give more informaton about the error

Comment: The error message will include a stack trace showing exactly what the problem is. Since the `$questions` variable is clearly passed to the view in the controller method you've shown us, the error is likely to be in another view or controller method.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to basics, rule out the issue being caused by `compact`.
If the following works:

```php
return view('admin.index', ['questions' => Question::all()]);
```

Then further investigation required.

- How would `compact` handle a `null` assignment, does it skip them?
- Is `Question::all()` returning `null` or an `empty array`?
- How would `@foreach` handle a `null` value?
- Should I ensure an empty array is presented instead of `null` value?

> Ask your self, why am I using `compact` at all?
>
> Why assign data to a var and cast it to an array item at the cost of performance (creating unnecessary memory pointers makes life for memory garbage collection harder negatively effecting concurrent user performance).

Comment: Null and undefined are 2 very different and unrelated things. The error quoted in the question specifically says the variable is undefined so it's likely the error is in some code not shown in the question.

Comment: `compact()` does not skip null variables. If `$questions` were null or empty, the error would not say "undefined variable" it would be a warning from `foreach` "argument must be of type array|object, null given." Regardless, Eloquent collection functions always return a Collection object, either empty or populated.

Answer (score 0):

Try Removing the eloquent relationship that's in the User and Question models

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. Before using loop, first check the data is empty or containing data
2. In case of null you can add ternary operator (eg: `$data->isEmpty()` in case of collection, `empty($data)` in case of array)